# The Name "myAnim" does not exist in the current context using visual studio for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call an animation that governs a player's invulnerability frames upon getting hit. I can't call a variable from my animation controller to interact with `myAnim.TriggerHurt(invincibleTimeAfterHurt);` and as a result I have this error. 
the two instances of `myAnim` in my animation controller are `Animator myAnim` and `myAnim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();`
I don't know why it's not working so any help anyone can provide is appreciated.

animation controller:

[image]

player controller:

[image]

Comment: worth putting some code in your question.

Comment: 1. Don't post links to code 2. Don't post images of code 3. `myAnim` is defined in a different class, so it's unclear why you'd expect it to be defined or accessible in `PlayerController`

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong with your code.

The function TriggerHurt() is defined in the AnimationController class.
Therefore you need to refer to this script (AnimationController.cs) in the PlayerController class. You could that as following (assuming both scripts are on the same GameObject)

```
public AnimationController animController;

void Start() 
{
    animController = gameObject.GetComponent<AnimationController>();
}
```

Then you call TriggerHurt() from the other script like this:

```
animController.TriggerHurt(invincibleTimeAfterHurt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
myAnim.TriggerHurt(invincibleTimeAfterHurt);
```

use

```
AnimationControlle.instance.TriggerHurt(invincibleTimeAfterHurt);
```